# Specializing a class template by a base class

Tags: c++, templates

I have distilled my doubt to this following piece of code

```
struct base {};
struct derived : public base {};

template <class T>
struct Type { };

template <> struct Type<base> {
  typedef float mytype;
};

typename Type<base>::mytype a=4.2;    // this works
typename Type<derived>::mytype a=4.2; // this doesnt
```

Could anyone explain why I cannot intantiate the class template object with `derived` and suggest a simple way to do it. For the actual problem that I am interested in there are many derived classes using which I want to intantiate template class objects and/or use typedefs. There are too many of them than what I would want to specialize individually.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, my bad, this needs to be C++03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct base { };
struct derived : base { };

template<typename T, bool = std::is_base_of<base, T>::value>
struct Type { };

template<typename T>
struct Type<T, true>
{
   typedef float mytype;
};

int main()
{
   Type<base>::mytype a1 = 4.2f;
   Type<derived>::mytype a2 = 8.4f;
   std::cout << a1 << '\n' << a2 << '\n';
}
```

In C++03, `std` can be trivially replaced with `boost`: [`boost::is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html)

Comment: Beware of C++11 `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: Yes, there is always [Boost.Type Traits](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html). Just with so many people still stuck with old pre-C++11 compilers (often Microsoft ones) a use of C++11 should be mentioned.

Comment: @JanHudec: I am using gcc... 4.3.2. The "enterprise" world is not so prompt to switch from proven technologies to new ones :x

Comment: @ildjarn I would like to do this for more than 1 hierarchy of classes. Say I had another hierarchy `struct AnotherBase` and `struct AnotherDerived: AnotherBase` and I have specialization in mind for Type<AnotherBase> but want an object of type Type<AnotherDerived> to use it. Is this possible ? I realize i left a lot outof my question

Comment: @san : Generally if the logic becomes complex one would write a traits class and dispatch/specialize based on that, but for only two hierarchies it may be simple enough to just use logical-OR: http://ideone.com/YdyqkN

Answer (score 3):

Two instantiations of a template class with different template arguments are *totally* unrelated class types. `Type<derived>` has no relation whatsoever to `Type<base>`, which of course means it doesn't use the specialisation and is instantiated from the primary template. The primary template has no nested type `mytype`.